# Get redirect link from window.location.href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I've been trying to find the redirect link from my code

```
r = c.get(url,headers=ua, timeout=15, allow_redirects=True)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

            print(soup)
```

Then it gave me a result like this

```
<script>

                         window.location.href = 'https://t.me/Claim_Litecoins_bot';

                         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                                    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'https://telegramfaucet.me/tonclick/Visit.php?c=3lj8a7rxq0', false);

                                    xmlHttp.send(null);

                                                                        window.location.href = 'https://t.me/Claim_Litecoins_bot';

                         </script>
```

So, how could i open the xmlHttp.open link?

I've using

```
if soup.find_all("a", href=True):
 print(soup)
```

But im not fin the link on
window.location.href

Comment: You can't use BeautifulSoup for that, because it's not an HTML tag.  What you have there is Javascript code.  If you really have that text in a string, you can use plain old Python string searching to find "xmlHttp.open" or "'GET'", and discern the location of the string from that.

Answer (score 0):

[beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) cannot parse javascript so you have to use another tool to get that link. One possibility is to use `re` module:

```py
import re


# the html_text comes from r.text in your script
html_text = '''\
<script>

                         window.location.href = 'https://t.me/Claim_Litecoins_bot';

                         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                                    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'https://telegramfaucet.me/tonclick/Visit.php?c=3lj8a7rxq0', false);

                                    xmlHttp.send(null);

                                                                        window.location.href = 'https://t.me/Claim_Litecoins_bot';

                         </script>'''


link = re.search(r"xmlHttp\.open\('GET', '([^']+)", html_text).group(1)
print(link)
```

Prints:

```
https://telegramfaucet.me/tonclick/Visit.php?c=3lj8a7rxq0
```